# Using remote sensing satellite for chlorophyll mapping?

Tags: data, remote-sensing, imagery, satellite

Location of my research are reservoirs which have an area of 47 and 62 km2.

I need a better image resolution than Landsat(Pan).

Comment: Some additional information on the temporal aspects are required to answer your question. Are you looking at deriving data for a single point in time, or do you want to establish a timeseries? What kind of budget do you have to do this?

Comment: both of them, single point in time and time series. 
I need suggestions for the best and better image resolution than Landsat 7(Pan), from most expensive to cheapest.

Comment: for a list of sensors that should be considered, take a look at this article: http://www.researchgate.net/profile/Salman_Ashraf/publication/42606259_Satellite_remote_sensing_for_mapping_vegetation_in_New_Zealand_freshwater_environments_A_review/links/00b495339fdfba304a000000.pdf in addition to the list on page 4, add WorldView-3, Pleiades and SPOT6 / SPOT7. The list and the pricings are a bit outdated and you should contact your local imagery reseller for up to date information.

Answer (score 3):

You could try the [MODIS Gridded Vegetation Indices](http://modis.gsfc.nasa.gov/data/dataprod/dataproducts.php?MOD_NUMBER=13).

I've worked with MODIS products before and can vouch for their quality, although I haven't done any chlorophyll analysis like the one that you mention.